# Injecting Commands into ViewModels

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm trying to figure out what is the right way to inject an `ICommand` into my ViewModel.

Given that my ViewModel looks like this.

```
public class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    ICommand LoadCommand { get; }
    ICommand SaveCommand { get; }
}
```

I currently do this in my constructor

```
public ViewModel(IRepository repository, IErrorLog errorLog, IValidator validator)
{
    LoadCommand = new LoadCommandImpl(repository, errorLog);
    SaveCommand = new SaveCommandImpl(repository, errorLog, validator);
}
```

Note that the parameters are not used by the ViewModel at all, aside from constructing the commands.

While I try to contain as much of the logic as possible in the injected interfaces, there is still logic in the commands.

It would seem more appropriate to do this

```
public ViewModel(ICommand loadCommand, ICommand saveCommand)
{
    LoadCommand = loadCommand;
    SaveCommand = saveCommand;

    LoadCommand.SetViewModel(this);
    SaveCommand.SetViewModel(this);
}
```

However to do this, I would need to make my Unity registrations like this.  Which isn't the end of the world, but it seems like a pain.

```
container.RegisterType<ICommand, LoadCommandImpl>("loadCommand");
container.RegisterType<ICommand, SaveCommandImpl>("saveCommand");

container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewModel>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<ICommand>("loadCommand"),
        new ResolvedParameter<ICommand>("SaveCommand")));
```

Alternatively, I could make `ILoadCommand` and `ISaveCommand` interfaces, but these interfaces would be empty or might implement `ICommand`.

I'm not a huge fan of any of these solutions.  What is the recommended approach here?

**Edit in response to blindmeis**

Let's pretend this is something other than commands for a moment.

```
public ViewModel(IFoo foo)
{
    Bar = new Bar(foo);
}
```

In my opinion, it would be more appropriate to just inject IBar

```
public ViewModel(IBar bar)
{
    Bar = bar;
}
```

But now I have `Bar1` and `Bar2`.  So I can either do

```
public ViewModel(IFoo foo)
{
    Bar1 = new Bar1(foo);
    Bar2 = new Bar2(foo);
}
```

or

```
public ViewModel(IBar bar1, IBar bar2)
{
    Bar1 = bar1;
    Bar2 = bar2;
}
```

Comment: why you want to inject the icommand at all? one purpose of a viewmodel is to expose viewlogic. if you want to inject a messageboxservice or things like that - i'm with you but a command belongs to the viewmodel. or do you want to reuse these command in any way?

Comment: @blindmeis Some of the commands can be reused.  But that is the whole point of my question.  If I am injecting parameters for the sole purpose of passing them to the commands, should I just be injecting the commands?

Comment: Yes you should pass in the Commands instead of the params to keep max flexibility. Passing in Commands for example will allow you to Mock your Command objects for testing. Futher more passing in commands will also allow you to build up the commands differently in the future eg allow each command to log to a differnt error log. Each object should be responsible for taking in its own params and building up its object graph. What benefits would you get from passing the params into your viewmodel?

Comment: i would do this then: public ViewModel(IBar bar1, IBar bar2). caa gives a good explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is not included in Unity but its not hard to retrofit.

```cs
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<MapParameterNamesToRegistrationNamesExtension>();
container.RegisterType<ICommand, LoadCommand>("loadCommand");
container.RegisterType<ICommand, SaveCommand>("saveCommand");
container.RegisterType<ViewModel>(new MapParameterNameToRegistrationName());
var vm = container.Resolve<ViewModel>();
Assert.IsType(typeof(LoadCommand), vm.LoadCommand);
Assert.IsType(typeof(SaveCommand), vm.SaveCommand);

public class MapParameterNamesToRegistrationNamesExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
  protected override void Initialize()
  {
    var strategy = new MapParameterNamesToRegistrationNamesStrategy();
    this.Context.Strategies.Add(strategy, UnityBuildStage.PreCreation);
  }
}
public class MapParameterNamesToRegistrationNamesStrategy : BuilderStrategy
{
  public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
  {
    if (context.Policies.Get<IMapParameterNameToRegistrationNamePolicy>(context.BuildKey) == null)
    {
      return;
    }
    IPolicyList resolverPolicyDestination;
    IConstructorSelectorPolicy selector = context.Policies.Get<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>(context.BuildKey, out resolverPolicyDestination);
    var selectedConstructor = selector.SelectConstructor(context, resolverPolicyDestination);
    if (selectedConstructor == null)
    {
      return;
    }
    var parameters = selectedConstructor.Constructor.GetParameters();
    var parameterKeys = selectedConstructor.GetParameterKeys();
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
    {
      Type parameterType = parameters[i].ParameterType;
      if (parameterType.IsAbstract || parameterType.IsInterface)
      {
        IDependencyResolverPolicy resolverPolicy = new NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy(parameterType, parameters[i].Name);
        context.Policies.Set<IDependencyResolverPolicy>(resolverPolicy, parameterKeys[i]);
      }
    }
    resolverPolicyDestination.Set<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>(new SelectedConstructorCache(selectedConstructor), context.BuildKey);
  }
}
public class MapParameterNameToRegistrationName : InjectionMember
{
  public override void AddPolicies(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, string name, IPolicyList policies)
  {
    policies.Set<IMapParameterNameToRegistrationNamePolicy>(new MapParameterNameToRegistrationNamePolicy(), new NamedTypeBuildKey(implementationType, name));
  }
}
public interface IMapParameterNameToRegistrationNamePolicy : IBuilderPolicy
{
}
public class MapParameterNameToRegistrationNamePolicy : IMapParameterNameToRegistrationNamePolicy
{
}
```

The code and test can be found in the source code of the [TecX project on CodePlex](http://tecx.codeplex.com). Project *TecX.Unity* (folder *Injection*).

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a command Factory

```
 public class CommandFactory (IUnityContainer container) : ICommandFactory
{
    public ICommand CreateSaveCommand()
    {
       return container.Resolve("SaveCommand");
    }
    public ICommand CreateLoadCommand()
     {
        return container.Resolve("LoadCommand");
    }
}

public ViewModel(ICommandFactory commandFactory)     
{         
    LoadCommand = commandFactory.CreateLoadCommand();         
    SaveCommand = commandFactory.CreateSaveCommand();         
}
```

Comment: So your solution is to take a single line statement `container.RegisterType<IViewModel, ViewModel>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<ICommand>("loadCommand"),
        new ResolvedParameter<ICommand>("SaveCommand")));` and replace it with a brand new interface and implementation that does the exact same thing?  Also, it doesn't really replace that line, it just shortens it.

Comment: well it depends why you feel the above line is "a pain"?